# Project Euler Program 5 takes too much time in Java

Tags: java

The question is:
What is the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to 20?

I write the following program which gives the correct output, but it took very long to execute.

What can I do to fasten my program?

```
    public class ep5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int n=100,k=0;
    boolean check=true;
    while(check)
    {   
        k=0;
        n++;

        for (int i=2;i<21;i++)
            if(n%i!=0)
                k=1;

        if (k!=1)
            check=false;
    }
    System.out.println(n);
}
}
```

Comment: Don't divide by all numbers `2...20`. If `n` is divisible by 20, it must be divisible by 2 as well. If you check against `20,19,18,17,16,15,14,13,12,11` instead of `2...20`, you'll get rid of a lot of overhead.

Comment: You can reduce some calculations by multiplying the value of n by the max number(20) because it has to be divisible by the max number. 20,40,60,80,100,120,140...

Comment: One other comment...in your loop where you set k=1, make that a break condition and bail out of the for loop. {k=1;break;}. All other calculations after k=1 are pointless

Comment: Have a look at the idea of the GCD (Greatest Common Denominator) of two numbers.

Comment: @rossum I think you mean LCM (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple), which is more relevant here.  The answer to the problem can be computed as simply as LCM(1,2,3,4,...,18,19,20)

Comment: Also, there are only 1024 subsets of `{11..20}`, so it's quicker to iterate over them instead of all possible results

Comment: @torquestomp `LCM(a, b) = (a . b) / GCD(a, b)`  Either can be used.  I happened to have a GCD() method in my maths library, so I used that.

Answer (score 1):

A start would be not to divide by multiples of two.

```
for (int i=3;i<21;i++){ //begin at i = 3
     i = i + 1; //count by twos
     if(n%2 !=0 && n%i!=0) //add a condition
          k=1;
}
```

I imagine you could extend this logic to multiples of 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, and 19, all the prime numbers between 1 and 21. Get rid of the for loop and use an else if statements to speed up the process.

```
if      (n%2 !=0)
     k = 1;
else if (n%3 != 0)
     k = 1;
else if (n%5 != 0)
     k = 1;
else if (n%7 != 0)
     k = 1;
else if (n%11 != 0)
     k = 1;
else if (n%13 != 0)
     k = 1;
else if (n%17 != 0)
     k = 1;
else if (n%19 != 0)
     k = 1;
else 
     check = false;
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

one can easily see that the smallest number that divide all numbers from 1 to 20 is the product of all (greatest power (of prime numbers smaller than 20) smaller than 20), you can manage to find those numbers and calculate there greater power that is smaller than 20 and multiply theses numbers

what I mathematically do is decompose all these numbers on prime numbers product, and take the biggest power for each prime number.

Comment: Be careful here.  A number with only one factor of two will not divide evenly into numbers like 20 or 16 which have more than one factor of two in them.  You need to modify your answer.

Comment: You answer would imply that correct answer would 2x3x5x7x11x13x17x19. However that is not divisible by 4 8 9 12 16 18 or 20.

Comment: I removed the last comment, and you are right i'll correct my answer